# Найти строку, заменить и сохранить все изменения в файле

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Проблема такая - надо открыть Html-файл на чтение, чтобы найти нужную строку, заменить ее на другую и записать в файл.
Делаю так, пока ничего не получается

```
 FileStream fi = new FileStream(@"C:\CP1.html", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,    FileAccess.ReadWrite);
 StreamReader rea = new StreamReader(fi);
 StreamWriter wri = new StreamWriter(fi,false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
 string time = GetTime();
        string t = "<tr><td>" + time +"</td> <td>" + Convert.ToString(Mheight) + "</td> <td>" + 
             Convert.ToString(Mspeed) + "</td> <td>" + Convert.ToString(Mtemp)+ "</td> </tr>";
        int i=0;

        do
            {
                i++;
                string str = rea.ReadLine();
                if (str == "<tr class=news-znak>")
                {
                    str = str.Replace("<tr class=news-znak>", t);
                    wri.WriteLine(str);
                    wri.WriteLine("<tr class=news-znak>");
                    goto label1;
                }

            } while (rea.Peek() != -1);
        label1:
        rea.Close();
        wri.Close();
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: **goto** ! кроме всего прочего, почему вы закрываете файл сразу после того как найдете нужную строку? (btw, у вас html файлы плохие, надо `<tr class='news-znak'> ` хотя-бы )

Comment: подчеркивает при инициализации синим цветом..почему?


     StreamReader rea = new StreamReader(fi);
        StreamWriter wri = new StreamWriter(fi, false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременное чтение и запись строк — не самая лучшая идея. Я бы использовал промежуточный файл:

```
string Filter(string s)
{
    if (s == "<tr class=news-znak>")
        return t;

    return s;
}

var srcPath = @"C:\CP1.html";
var tempPath = srcPath + ".temp";

var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
File.WriteAllLines(tempPath,
                   File.ReadLines(srcPath, enc).Select(Filter)
                   enc);
File.Delete(srcPath);
File.Move(tempPath, srcPath);
```

Comment: File.WriteAllLines( tempPath, File.ReadAllLines(srcPath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Select(Filter), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) );


    Пишет что Select  недоступен как метод ((

Comment: Хм, странно. (1) Какая у вас версия .NET? (2) Вы не забыли `using System.Linq`?

Comment: я немного по-другому сделала, но сам алгоритм с промежуточным файлом помог. спасибо Вам, все получилось))

Comment: Регулярками все красивее бы было :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: устройство функции `Filter` может быть любым, хоть с регулярками, хоть с ручным парсингом. :-)

Comment: Ульяна_Север: а с Select не вышло? Должно быть что-то вроде этого: http://pastebin.com/pP7PWQWb

Comment: @ReinRaus: хотя, на перле это был бы однострочник, да. С регулярками и всяческой красотой.